# can I re-add the original namesaver after adding cloudflare namesaver?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, cloudflare, cdn

I have a webhosting website which will cause failure for clients who try creating sub-domain when I change my nameserver with cloudflare nameserver.

I am thinking to re-add my original nameserver after cloudflare verify my change of nameserver. Will both nameservers work?
Hosing website is [sonafree.com](https://sonafree.com/hosting/)

Comment: if you have still the infrastructure then you can revert back to the original state. but you ca  ot mix both together

Answer (score 0):

No. If you switch back the nameserver to the one used previously, cloudflare will notice (it may take even a few days) and will deactivate your site.

Please note that cloudflare provides DNS API and it should be possible to create sub-domains from the website.